# GFI tripping - remove to continue circuit to other GFI's working fine

Tags: electrical

This feed comes from a 3 gang box.  12/2 20amp.  3 GFI's on one circuit.  The 1st GFI constantly trips and cannot be reset.  The other 2 GFI's work fine after removing the 1st GFI in the series.  I've been through 2 GFI outlets now with the same results.  Why is the 1st GFI in this circuit of 3 GFI's constantly tripping and cannot be reset but when removed to complete the circuit the other 2 GFI's work fine.

Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: So are you saying you have 3 gfi outlets in the same 3gang box? If so, WHY? Are any of them wired to downstream outlets???Esp. the one that won't reset?   Is this a new problem? If so, what changes have you made?  A single GFI outlet is able to protect the other 2 outlets in the 3 gang box and any down stream outlets.  Please add more info  so we can better help you.

Comment: As others have already said, you don't need 3 GFIs in one box, but if you could edit your question to add a pic or drawing of how you have them wired I'm sure someone could point out the problem. My guess would be that you're running the other 2 GFIs off the Load terminal of the 1st one, but you've pigtailed all the neutrals together

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to have 3 GFIs in series. If wired correctly (Hot lead on Line and Lead to continue the circuit on Load) The first GFI will protect everything downstream.  I have encountered GFIs opening unnecessarily because of multiples in the circuit.  Take out the 2 GFIs down stream and put just the one at the beginning of then circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Two options.

1. Bad GFCI (in which case moving one of the other two to this location
   will fix it)
2. Ground fault between this GFCI location and the (un-needed if this is wired correctly) other two GFCIs. They don't care about ground faults upstream of them, they can't see those. Any ground fault downstream of them they will trip for, which is why 3 in series is needless.

Since you've apparently tried replacing it twice, option 2 is your most likely issue.

It's doing what it's supposed to do.

Fix the bad wiring between those points and it will stop protecting you from it.

Ground and neutral being shorted is by far the most common ground fault. Improperly shared neutrals between circuits is likely the second most common. Truly weird things not in a junction box are rare indeed (less than 1/10th of a percent, I'd estimate. Problems are almost always in junction boxes.)